# WCF service Testing Tools sending *.xml file

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have valid *.xml files generated based on WCF service. I want to test the WCF service using the *.xml file. Currently, I have to programmatically load the *.xml file, initialise service object with *.xml file, and send the request.

Is there tool that avoids programming, and can test the WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

The WCF Test Client is a great tool to test your services (and you already have it)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx

If you need something a little more flexible and powerful, check out Storm:
http://storm.codeplex.com/

With Storm you can manipulate the requests and trace out the interaction.

Of course you could always just use Fiddler to make your own web requests.